# Python dict.values comparison

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried to compare dict.values and I get weird result.

```py
a = dict()
print(a.keys() == a.keys())  # True
print(a.values() == a.values())  # False
print(a.values().__eq__(a.values()))  # NotImplemented
# but
values = a.values()
print(values == values)  # True
print(values.__eq__(values))  # True
```

Do you have any ideas why it works like that?

Comment: Because values creates a ValuesView object.

Comment: And keys create a dict_keys object, but how does that explain equality/inequality as tried above